# Problems with QDialog in Qt

Tags: qt, qdialog

I'm using Qt for Symbian. I have some problems with a QDialog that I open from a QMenu. The QDialog shows up fine and in the QDialog I have a QDialogButtonBox with a button to Close the QDialog. BUT if I close the QDialog and then open it from the QMenu again, it will show up but the button from the QDialogButtonBox will not show up. Instead the buttons from the QMainWindow will show but they are grayed out.

How can I get the QDialog buttons to show every time? Maybe I have some problems with setting focus on the QDialog? I really can't see what I'm doing wrong here.

It's not much code that I use, you can try it yourself. This is my code:

In QMainWindow I use the following to create the menu:

```
QAction *menuButton = new QAction("Menu", this);
menuButton->setSoftKeyRole(QAction::PositiveSoftKey);

QMenu *menu = new QMenu(this);
menuButton->setMenu(menu);

QAction *popup = new QAction("Show popup",this);
connect(popup, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(showPopup()));
menu->addAction(popup);

addAction(menuButton);
```

This shows the QDialog:

```
void MyMainWindow::showPopup(){
TestDialog *test = new TestDialog(this);
test->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
test->show();
}
```

This is the TestDialog:

```
TestDialog::TestDialog(QWidget *parent)
: QDialog(parent)
{
ui.setupUi(this);
QDesktopWidget* desktopWidget = QApplication::desktop();
QRect rect = desktopWidget->availableGeometry();
this->setFixedWidth(rect.width());
}
```

Comment: I don't have access to Symbian, but I've had problems with dialogs in the past.  One of the things that I would try is change your constructor of TestDialog to "TestDialog *test = new TestDialog();"  Note there is no parent object in constructor call.

Normally I would could this the way you did if I wanted to constrain the dialog box within frame of main window.   But on Symbian, I don't see this as a problem.  I'm not posting this as an answer as I cannot try it out.

Comment: I'm used to calling exec on dialogs when i want them to pop up and interact. show should work, but exec might be worth to try.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your dialog to be modal, use exec(). Otherwise, you should use show() and raise() to make sur it's on top.